# How to separate a database from a Django web-app when going live?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, server

I need this in order to host a database (MySQL) and an application server on the different servers. Is it even possible? If yes, is that a good idea at all?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. In fact, it is even considered a best practice to separate app and database servers.

[This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul-pHtOfA9U) gives good examples with illustrations about that.

Let's say you have your app server with ip `189.23.32.32`. Then, you create a database server (with IP 100.10.10.5) and in your server and mysql config files you say that you want to allow requests from this IP on this particular port.

Then, in your Django settings you say that you want to connect to that database. For postgres, it would look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': '100.10.10.5',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
    },
}
```

In order to adapt it to MySQL, just change the ENGINE part and you should be good.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will definitely check out the video. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me (or direct to somebody who can help) with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972449/hosting-a-web-app-on-a-cloud-outside-of-a-companys-it-infrastructure-security