# Is there anyway to protect Django source code from being revealed, after giving server access to the client?

Tags: python, django, database, docker, source-code-protection

After deploying a Django project and giving server access to the client, is there anyway to protect the source code from being revealed?

Maybe somthing like seperating the servers for holding the database and the source code?
Or having some lock or something on the docker container of the Django project?

Comment: You can convert it to executable binary or other language. Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913847/is-there-a-way-to-compile-a-python-application-into-static-binary

Comment: What reason does the client need access to the server. You could have the django code owned by user x and have the client connect as user y assuming the client user doesn't have   access to sudo or the likes. compiling to an exe etc offers little protection as they can normally just be decompiled

Comment: Can you explain what the client needs server access for? Do they want to use it to change and debug your code, for example? If so it's probably impossible to satisfy both parties here. Is there some reduced form of access you can give them?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle
The client wants the database under his protection!!! Only The database matters to him.

Comment: @NickODell
The client wants the database under his protection!!! Only The database matters to him.

Comment: @ruddra I don't think that is possible for Django projects! Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, Django can run on a different server than the database server, and connect to the database server over the network.

Comment: You could run the data base as user X and the django app as user Y and make all the django files owned by user Y only readable by user Y that way the client logging in as user X wont be able to read them

Comment: @NickODell How can I do that? Can you please give instructions as an answer to the question?

Comment: @Mohawo Here's an example of how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973381/how-to-separate-a-database-from-a-django-web-app-when-going-live